# do <= and >= relational operators work with Integer objects

Tags: java

I understand that you can't use == or != to compare values of numeric objects and have to use .equals() instead. But after a fair amount of searching I haven't been able to find a statement about whether or not you can use the other comparison operators, other than suggestions to use .compare() or .compareTo() which feel inefficient because they require two comparisons: a to b, then the result of that to zero.

Despite == and != comparing the addresses of the objects, the other comparison operators appear to compare the numeric values. For instance the following code snippet:

```
Integer a = new Integer(3000);
Integer b = new Integer(3000);
System.out.println("a <  b " + (a < b));
System.out.println("a <= b " + (a <= b));
System.out.println("a == b " + (a == b));
System.out.println("a >= b " + (a >= b));
System.out.println("a >  b " + (a > b));
```

produces

```
a <  b false
a <= b true
a == b false
a >= b true
a >  b false
```

Which appears to indicate all operators but == compare the value, not the address of the object. Is it accepted usage to use the <= class of operators, or just an unsupported feature of my compiler or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, but note that `Integer` are **objects**, not primitive `int`. Usage of `>`, `<`, `>=` and `<=` operators are not meant for objects, but for primitives, so when using any of these, the `Integer` is autoboxed to `int`. While when using `==` in objects you are comparing their references. Use `equals` instead to compare them.

Still, note that `Integer` class has an cache that store `Integer` references from `-128` to `127`. This means that if you do this:

```
Integer i1 = 127;
Integer i2 = 127;
System.out.println(i1 == i2);
```

Will print `true`.